# fastlane debugging error messages

Tags: ios, hybrid-mobile-app, fastlane

When I run a `lane` in fastlane (`fastlane ios beta`), all I see is this :

```
Successfully submitted crash report. If this is a problem with one of the tools you want to report
please submit an issue on GitHub and attach the following number to it: '2657a36b29e2cc2db1254ed90e5f4add'
Also stored the crash report locally '/tmp/sentry_2657a36b29e2cc2db1254ed90e5f4add.json'
```

Is there anyway to debug the problem? Also, I dont see the `tmp/`folder anywhere to look at the json file generated.

Answer (score 0):

While I realize this question is fairly old, and fastlane's error handling has actually changed a lot since then... I'll provide a quick suggestion.

*fastlane* tries not to overwhelm people with error information by default, since that can often make the one message that matters hard to see or discover. If you ever want *fastlane* to print more error information, including a stack trace for crashes, you can run fastlane with the `--verbose` flag.